# Why does the double get rounded off?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

With the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const double pi = 3.14159;

int main() {

double x;
cin >> x; 

cout << "A=" << pi * x * x << endl; 

return 0; 
}
```

And inputting

100.64

I get the value 31819.3, while what I want is 31819.3103

I tried using set precision but that doesn't seem to work either. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: Here's some interesting reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: https://ideone.com/9QdKYo <- `setprecision` works, but it's the number of digits not the number of decimals.

Comment: BTW, don't use the non-standard header `bits/stdc++.h`.  Get in the habit of only including necessary header files.